how do i remove the pop-up windows background from MUI?
i want to remove the white pop-up background of mui's default css.
 <Dialog
        open={open}
        onClose={() => {
          setOpen(false);
        }}
      >
        <DialogContent>
          <h1>are you sure to logout?</h1>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button>yes</Button>
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                setOpen(false);
              }}
            >
              no
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>

I didn't find a solution yet.

The question is kind of hard to understand but I interpet two possible questions:

Remove the "white pop-up background" aka. the background of the dialog, which is white. (Which I think, is the question the author has in mind)
Remove the backdrop of the dialog.

1:
  <Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={() => {
      setOpen(false);
    }}
    sx={{
      "& .MuiPaper-root": {
        background: "transparent",
      },
    }}
  >
    <DialogContent>
      <h1>are you sure to logout?</h1>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button>yes</Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            setOpen(false);
          }}
        >
          no
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>

Inside the Dialog component tags, I added an extra property sx, which is an additional way to add custom styles to MUI components. (if you want to read more: https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/ )
Inside the sx property you can access classes created by the MUI system (or just use "normal" css properties), in this case for example: the MuiPaper-root class. By adding background: "transparent", the background property of MuiPaper-root is overwritten. Why do I know the class to change? A quick way to check the classes is to use the web console and check the DOM structure:
classes in the MUI dialog component
Usually the first class, is the one you want. The other way is to check the API documentation of the MUI component. At the bottom of the documentation are usually the css classes. Unfortunately if we set the background to transparent, this is now the result:MUI dialog background is grey instead of white. I think these informations is enough to play with the styling of MUI components and get the desired result you want.
2: To hide or remove the backdrop, you can simply do:
  <Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={() => {
      setOpen(false);
    }}
    hideBackdrop
  >
    <DialogContent>
      <h1>are you sure to logout?</h1>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button>yes</Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => {
            setOpen(false);
          }}
        >
          no
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </DialogContent>
  </Dialog>

You can add simply hideBackdrop as an property to the Dialog component. (https://mui.com/material-ui/api/modal/)
If you want to change the backdrop color, do this:
  <Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={() => {
      setOpen(false);
    }}
    sx={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}
  >


thz you for answering me

If the answer was helpful and a solution, pls accept the answer as a solution :)
